# How to fetch the value in object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I would like to know how to get/fetch the object in nested array using javascript.

```
var value = "SGD"
var obj=[{
  country: singapore,
  ccy: ["EUR","SGD"]
  amount: "1000"
},{
  country: thailand,
  ccy: ["THB"]
  amount: "1000"
}]

function getData(){
 return obj.filter((e)=>{
    return e.ccy == value; // fetch array object if it matches the value
  }
}

var result = getData();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `e.ccy.includes(value)` should work

Comment: you'll want a combination of map/filter ... or maybe find or something

Comment: @georg - no, includes returns a boolean, not an object

Comment: @JaromandaX: I have no idea what the OP is asking, and neither do you. Until they post their code and example output all we can do is to make more or less accurate guesses.

Comment: I know exactly what they are asking @georg - the clue is *in the question* ... `fetch array object if it matches the value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the array of objects that includes the selected currency in the variable `value` you can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const value = 'SGD';
const obj = [{country: 'singapore',ccy: ['EUR', 'SGD'],amount: '1000'}, {country: 'thailand',ccy: ['THB'],amount: '1000'}];
const getData = (arr, value) => arr.filter(o => o.ccy.includes(value));

const result = getData(obj, value);
console.log(result);
```

Note that instead of a function `getData` using variables out of function scope it is better pass the parameters you need in the function `getData(obj, value)`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question, but if you want the *first* matching entry in the array, you're looking for the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) on `ccy` in the search:

```
function getData(){
    return obj.find(e => e.ccy.includes(value));
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var value = "SGD";
var obj= [{
  country: "singapore",
  ccy: ["EUR","SGD"],
  amount: "1000"
},{
  country: "thailand",
  ccy: ["THB"],
  amount: "1000"
}];

function getData() {
  return obj.find(e => e.ccy.includes(value));
}

var result = getData();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.ccy` is an array. Comparing it with any other variable will never return `true` unless both have same reference. To check if the element is present in array using `Array.prototype.includes()`

```js
var value = "SGD";
var obj=[{
  country: 'singapore',
  ccy: ["EUR","SGD"],
  amount: "1000"
},{
  country: 'thailand',
  ccy: ["THB"],
  amount: "1000"
}]

function getData(){
 return obj.filter((e)=>{
    return e.ccy.includes(value)
  })
}

var result = getData();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj=[{
  country: 'singapore',
  ccy: ["EUR","SGD"],
  amount: "1000"
},{
  country: 'thailand',
  ccy: ["THB"],
  amount: "1000"
}]

function getData(val) {
   var result = obj.find(function(o) {
   return o.ccy.indexOf(val) > -1;
   });
return result;
}

console.log(getData('SGD'));
```